# CSS is not allowing a border size of 1, it's forcefully rendering a size of 3 on pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I have a p element with a class of el that i'm using to simply display a line of text. I also am utilizing a pseudo element on that element that I would like to be 1 pixel in height. Since I want just a visible line, I have added a styling rule for border-top: 1px to this pseudo element but it's being rendered strange in chrome. It actually seems to be 3px in height and dev tools is in fact showing 3 pixels. When i then try to change the height to 1px from within the computed section in dev tools, it changes the value straight back to 3px. What could this be? I am setting device width with a meta tag and can confirm my view isn't zoomed and is at 100%

```
.el {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.el:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

jsfiddle showing the border correctly... https://jsfiddle.net/2sa74g94/5/

Edit: after some experimenting it seems to be that the font-size of the parent element, p, is causing the pseudo element to render differently. FYI, the p has a font pulled in from google fonts.

Changing the font size up and down makes the border render correctly and clean at 1px or sub-pixeled and at 3px.

EDIT again: take a fresh look at the jsfiddle. Focus on the p element with dev tools and change the font-size from 1.5em to 2.5ems with chrome. You should see the border size change.

Comment: Are you saying the border is showing 3 px? I just checked the fiddle and it is showing 1px.

Comment: @ibu I narrowed it down to font-size when combined with transform: translateY.. see more info above

Comment: why do you add a space inside `content:""` let the value of content with only `""` with nothing between the `"` (double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `background-color` on the `:before` element instead of a `border-top` to make it work. The pseudo-element can have a height of just `1px` and a `width: 100px;`.

```css
    p {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

p:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: black; /*Removed border, added background-color */
}
```

```html
<p>
this is some text
</p>
```

Comment: I wish I could say this worked. But it actually didn't! Very weird as I was sure it would fix it. After some experimenting, it's actually the font-size of the parent element. I will add this new info to the post.

Comment: Then I think it's because the space inside your `content: " ";`. Glad you found the answer though.